# Guideline on how to set InfiniDB options?

Tags: mysql, storage-engines, infinidb

I've been trying to find out how to best set these settings, but haven't been able to find much info on them. Some of them I've seen before with regular MySQL installations, but some others I haven't:

```
## InfiniDB Specific options
sort_buffer_size = 4M
read_buffer_size = 4M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 16M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size = 0
thread_stack = 512K
join_buffer_size = 128M
#infinidb_compression_type=0
```

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

InfiniDb is built upon MySql, and these values are all standard MySql system variables. When deciding on their values, reference the MySql documentation. 
Descriptions can be found here: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html